# Get second level value from an object with a variable

Tags: javascript

I am making a function where i give the object path in a variable. I use this function after i got my data from the database.

```
function find(object, path, cb) {
  return cb(object[path]);
}

var object = {user:{firstname:"bob"}};
find(object, "user", function(data){});
```

This works fine with objects on the first level of the object but what if i want a object from the second level or higher:

```
"user.firstname"
```

When i try to run this through the find function wil it give a not defined error. How can i improve my function?

Comment: Maybe that is just a simplified example, but I don't really see the point of the find function when you could just do `(function(data){})(object.user.firstname)`.

Comment: Hmm maybe a good idea to just do that. I think that i was thinking to difficult :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it manually by [`split` function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) and iteratively executing this pattern:

```
var properties = path.split(".");
var value = obj;
for(prop of properties)
{
  value = value[prop];
}
```

Comment: when i try to use for(prop of properties) it gives a Unexpected identifier error on "prop"

Comment: Ow sorry i had forgot to link data to the "value" variable

Answer (score 1):

You could make your find function **recursive**. Besides making the path an array instead of a string gives you the option to do this for multiple layers.

```
function find (object, path, cb) {
    if (path.length > 1) return find(object[path.shift()], path, cb);
    return cb(object[path.pop()]);
}
var object = {user: {firstname:"bob"}};
find(object, ["user","firstname"], function (data){console.log(data)});
```